# Iterate through json objects to add unique values to new list with python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to iterate through a json response to get the elements for each array element in the response and add those to a new json object. I am making multiple calls that get a new json response, but also could return the same id from a previous call. I want to loop through all of the calls and have a list of unique id the end.

example json response

```
[{"firstName" : "John",
  "lastName"  : "Doe",
  "id:"       : "123542"
  },
  {"firstName" : "Jane",
  "lastName"  : "Doe",
  "id:"       : "123"
  },
  {"firstName" : "Harry",
  "lastName"  : "dude",
  "id:"       : "653"
  }
 ]
```

What I have right now but doesn't remove the dups. It just adds every single

```
new_members = []
for team in teams
    if team["name"] == "example":
        members = call_to_get_members.json()

        for member in members:
            new_member = {"firstName": member["firstName"], "lastName": member["lastName"]}
            if member not in new_members:
                new_members.append(new_member)
                break
```

Comment: if you only want one occurance, why not use sets?

Comment: @Karl `dict`s are not hashable, so can not be placed in a set. The OP would need to use tuples.

Comment: @kdopen the user data from the json is very hashable, such as the id field which he seems to indicate is a unique field.

Comment: Yes it is, but the OP is creating a dict. This code has many more problems than the one they are asking about, at least if I'm reading the 'spec' correctly for the problem they need to solve. I've seen that `call_to_get_members` before so I think this is an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a typo in this line:

```
new_member = {"firstName": member["firstName"] + "lastName": member["lastName"]}
```

The `+` should be a comma.

The reason it is adding every entry lies in this `if` statement

```
if member not in new_members:
```

I believe you want

```
if new_member not in new_members:
```

Without seeing the output of `call_to_get_members.json()`, I have to assume it returns a list of `dict`s, each containing the first name, last name, **and user id** for each member. Thus, `member` will never match anything in `new_members` as the `dict`s in that list do not have an `id` field.

This results in the append happening every time.